# Openlayers controls outside the map

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, geoext

I want put OpenLayers controls outside a map but dont know how.  I find this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editingtoolbar-outside.html but its not what i want.  I have a button and want to edit my WFS layer by click this button. So i need in

```
OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(wfs, {
    title: "Modify Feature",
    displayClass: "olControlModifyFeature"
});
```

So how to put this in button? And i use a geoext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
                         editButton= new Ext.Button({
                                tooltip: "Edit",
                                id: "commit_changes",
                                text: "Edit",
                                hidden: false,
                                handler: function(){
create= new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(myVecLayer,
                                            OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);
                                    app.mapPanel.map.addControl(create);
                                    create_cont=app.mapPanel.map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature");
                                }

                           }
```

Something like this. Some controls needed for activate option.

Answer (score 2):

I did not go through that problem yet, but what you are asking maybe similar to this: 
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2007-October/003093.html

regards,
Joaquim Muchaxo.
Portugal.

Comment: How can i see in your example control panel putting outside a map. But i want to call `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature` by click on Extjs button.

Comment: Hi I have not used ExtJs to have experience to help you on that, however I can help with OL so maybe if you post more of your code, perhaps I or someone else can help.